# Pure css implementation of google photos

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to accomplish layout same of google photos and come across to this page https://github.com/xieranmaya/blog/issues/6 . My question is about the final output of his work which can be viewed on this page. https://xieranmaya.github.io/images/cats/cats.html . When you inspect element one of the photos you can see this line

```
<div ng-repeat="img in imgs" style="flex-grow:70.57291666666667;flex-basis:169.375px;" class="ng-scope">

  <img ng-src="stock-photo-34598868.jpg" src="stock-photo-34598868.jpg">
</div>
```

My Question is what computation did he use to get the value of flex-grow and flex-basis since it's not mentioned on the tutorial?

Comment: This is really something you should ask the developer directly.

Comment: Inspecting the page you can see that it's made in Angular and the flex grow factor is `style="flex-grow:{{img.width*100/img.height}};flex-basis:{{img.width*240/img.height}}px;">`

Comment: @Blazemonger, Thanks I already did that. Just waiting for his reply. Just post it here in case someone knows it.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi, Thanks I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see that with jQuery I simulate the flex grow effect as seen in the Angular version.

```
$('img').each(function() {  //Cycle all the images
var img = $(this);

//Apply flex settings
img
    .css('flex-grow', img.width() * 100 / img.height())
    .css('flex-basis', img.width() * 240 / img.height() + 'px');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/gvzg81pf/)

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for. You're awesome.